# Finding incorrect yml headers

Tags: python, regex, validation, file-system

[image]

## Introduction

I am working on a semi large project with a few hundred files. In this project there is a series of *lesson.yml* files I want to check is formatted correctly. And, yes, every file I want is called exactly that.

*Just to clarify my code works, and does exactly what I want. However, I expect there either exists a better method, or that the code can be cleaned up significantly.*

The files look exactly like this

```
level: 1-4
    topic: [tags1]
    subject: [tags2]
    grade: [tags3]
```

or this

```
indexed: false
    topic: [tags1]
    subject: [tags2]
    grade: [tags3]
```

If the file starts with `indexed: false` it should be skipped.

The title `level:` has to be from 1 to 4. Every file must have the titles *topic*, *subject* and *grade*, and only one of them . The tags can only be any of the words below.

```
 topic_tags: app|electronics|step_based|block_based|text_based|minecraft|web|game|robot|animation|sound|cryptography,
 subject_tags: mathematics|science|programming|technology|music|norwegian|english|arts_and_crafts|social_science
 grade: preschool|primary|secondary|junior|senior
```

### Test cases

```
level: 9
tags:
    topic: [block_based, game]
    subject: [programming]
    grade: [primary, secondary, junior]
```

This should output the `filepath` then `level: 9` with the *9* in red, as only levels 1-4 is supported.

```
level: 3
tags:
    topic: [text_based]
    subject: [mathematics, programming, yodeling]
    grade: [junior, senior]
```

This should output the line the `filepath` then `subject: [mathematics, programming, yodeling]` where the word *yodeling* is marked in red, as it is not a valid subject (even if most of us think it should be).

```
level: 1
```

This should output `filepath: missing: topic, subjects, grade` where topic, subjects, and grade is marked in red.

```
level: 9
tags:
    topic: [block_based, game]
    subject: [programming]
    grade: [primary, secondary, junior]
    grade: [primary, junior]
```

This one should output filepath then `extra: grade` as there is more than one grade.

### Results

Running the code on my database returns something like this

[image]

## Code

```
import glob
from termcolor import colored
from collections import defaultdict
import re

tags_ = dict(
    level="[1-4]",
    topic=
    "app|electronics|step_based|block_based|text_based|minecraft|web|game|robot|animation|sound|cryptography",
    subject=
    "mathematics|science|programming|technology|music|norwegian|english|arts_and_crafts|social_science",
    grade="preschool|primary|secondary|junior|senior",
)


# If a file starts with "indexed: false" skip it
def is_indexed(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        first_line = f.readline().replace(" ", "").lower().strip()
        return first_line != "indexed:false"


# Colors the words from bad_words red in a line
def color_incorrect(bad_words, line):
    line = re.sub('(' + '|'.join(bad_words) + ')', '{}', line)
    return line.format(*[colored(w, 'red') for w in bad_words])


def find_incorrect_titles(title_count, titles):
    missing = []
    extra = []
    for title in titles:
        if title_count[title] > 1:
            extra.append(colored(title, 'red'))
        elif title_count[title] < 1:
            missing.append(colored(title, 'red'))
    miss_str = 'missing: ' + ', '.join(missing) if missing else ''
    extra_str = 'extra: ' + ', '.join(extra) if extra else ''
    if miss_str:
        return miss_str + ' | ' + extra_str if extra_str else miss_str
    else:
        return extra_str


def find_incorrect_tags(filename):
    title_count = defaultdict(int)  # Counts number of titles, topics, etc
    incorrect_tags = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            for title, tag in tags_.items():
                if not line.startswith(title):
                    continue
                title_count[title] += 1
                n = True

                # Finds every non-legal tag as defined at the start of the file
                regex = r'\b(?!{0}|{1}\b)\w+'.format(title, tag)
                m = re.findall(regex, line)  # Places the words in a list
                if m:  # If we got any hits, this means the words are wrong
                    line = color_incorrect(m, line)  # color the words

                # This block finds titles without any legal words (empty).
                else:
                    if title != "level":
                        regex_legal = r'{0}: *\[( *({1}),? *)+\]'.format(
                            title, tag)
                    else:
                        regex_legal = r'{0}: *( *({1}),? *)+'.format(
                            title, tag)
                        n = re.search(regex_legal, line)
                    # If no legal words has been found, color the line red
                    if not n:
                        line = colored(line, 'red')

                if m or not n:  # Add line to list of incorrect tags
                    incorrect_tags.append(
                        (' ' * 4 if title != "level" else " ") + line)
                break

    # We find if any title, topic, subject does not appear exactly once
    return (incorrect_tags, title_count)


def print_incorrect_titles_and_tags(filename):
    incorrect_tags, title_count = find_incorrect_tags(filename)
    incorrect_titles = find_incorrect_titles(title_count, tags_.keys())
    # If any errors are found we print them
    if incorrect_titles or incorrect_tags:
        print(colored(filename, 'yellow') + ": " + incorrect_titles)
        print('\n'.join(incorrect_tags)) if incorrect_tags else ''


if __name__ == "__main__":

    path = '../oppgaver/src'
    files = glob.glob(path + '/**/lesson.yml', recursive=True)

    for f in files:
        if is_indexed(f):
            print_incorrect_titles_and_tags(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an odd statement:

```
print('\n'.join(incorrect_tags)) if incorrect_tags else ''
```

It produces the return value of `print()`, if `incorrect_tags` is truthy, otherwise it produces `''`.

If the `print()` is executed, it concatenates possibly many strings together, with a newline separator just to print them.  The last line's newline comes from the print statement itself.  Somewhat confusing.  The following is less tricky, and much clearer:

```
for incorrect_tag in incorrect_tags:
    print(incorrect_tag)
```

---

Promiscuous regex:

```
def color_incorrect(bad_words, line):
    line = re.sub('(' + '|'.join(bad_words) + ')', '{}', line)
    return line.format(*[colored(w, 'red') for w in bad_words])
```

If the line `subject: [arts_and_crafts, mathematics, programming, art]` is encountered, `art` becomes a bad word, and `line` becomes:

```
'subject: [{}s_and_crafts, mathematics, programming, {}]'
```

The subsequent `line.format(...)` will generate the exception:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Prevent this using `\b` word boundary assertions:

```
line = re.sub(r'\b(' + '|'.join(bad_words) + r')\b', '{}', line)
```